# having problems showing div with css

Tags: css

Here is the structure I'm using.

```
<div id="p-menu" class="menu">
<ul>        
    <li>
        <a href="#">Top List Links</a>
    </li>        
    <li><span>Top Link List with dropdown</span> 
         <a href="#" class="linkArrow"><img src="Arrow.png"" /></a>
         <ul>                
            <li><a href="#">Horizontal Links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I would like is for the image to reveal the list of "horizontal links" just under the arrow image. For the life of me I can't get it to show up on hover. I have tried to use the following css:

```
.linkArrow:hover ul { display:block; }
```

But it won't reveal it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list item that you're trying to show isn't nested inside your anchor, thats why the CSS you wrote isn't showing the ul.

If you want to keep the same structure then you can use the sibling selector

```
.linkArrow:hover + ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That displays it but once you move off of it to go down the list it does not stay revealed. Should I encapsulate the list in a div?

Comment: If you're looking to have the `<ul>` permanently displayed when you hover over the `<a>` you're most likely going to have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. I had heard you could do it without jQuery but will just go ahead and use it for now. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a thought here, you could also add a hover that UL so if you're hovering over the UL while it'll stay open. 

`.linkArrow + ul:hover { display: block }`

But of course if you hover out of the UL then it will hide.

Answer (score 1):

The `ul` you want to display is not a descendant of `.linkArrow`.  You can use the sibling combinator, however -- `~` or `+` should both work in this case.

```
.linkArrow:hover ~ ul { display:block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/At69f/

Comment: Depending on your browser support `~` would be a good idea because it doesn't require the elements to be immediately next to each other, but if you need some older IE support then `+` would be the way to go.

Comment: Sibling selectors work in IE8 and up, however HTML comments break them in IE7.